# How To Publish/Create Installer For A C# Application With An SQLite Database?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sqlite, installation

I have a simple WinForms Application written in C# using Visual Studio which includes a SQLite Database..
The Database’s Build Action Property is set to “Content” and the Copy To Output Directory is set to “Copy if Newer”.
The application is ready for publishing. I’d like to make an installer. What is the best way to go about this? 
I anticipate a few problems.. Where should I save the database file? If it gets saved into the Program Files Folder, the Database would become Read-Only.. Where should I save it and how should I go about doing so?

Comment: My personal recomendation is [WiX](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/). You may also read about [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) (simpler way)

Comment: Hey thanks for you answer.. I guess my question was more about where to locate the database.. So far I’ve been using Inno Setup and adding the database to the Program Files Folder and I keep getting a Read-Only Error.. Do you happen to know how I should go about making an installer so that this doesn’t happen?

Comment: ok, this worth an answer. I will write one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will take your question as: *"Where to store writable files during installation and use of application?"*

There is 2 special places for this:

1. **ApplicationData** special folder. This folder is accessable by current user and is actually placed in *C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming* (Win7). This path is stored in `%APPDATA%` environment variable and can be used like this:

   ```
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
   ```

   You may safely store your files in following folder structure there: `%APPDATA%\YourCompanyName\YourAppName\`.
2. **CommonApplicationData** special folder. Almost the same as above, except it is accessable by *all* users and is actually placed in __ (Win7). This path is stored in `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` environment variable and can be used like this:

   ```
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData));
   ```

   As before, you may safely store your files in following folder structure there: `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\YourCompanyName\YourAppName\`.

As for your case, here how you can get a db filepath:

```
var appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
var dbPath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "YourCompanyName\YourAppName", "your_db_name.sqlite3");
```

Real difference is: does this database are common for *all* windows users, or *each* user should have his own database.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed! So if I understood correctly.. I will make my installer save all the files into the ProgramFiles folder, but then I’ll save the database into the AppData folder.. This would make the path for the database variable, so I need to change my connection string with the help of the Environment.GetFolderPath.. Is this right? If so, how do I go about selecting which I files get installed into which folders? Thanks!

Comment: You may try to use environment variable (`%APPDATA%`) inside of your connection strings (I'm not sure if this works fine). As for selecting files - I'm not sure what you mean:\ db to "AppData", all other to "Program Files"?

Comment: Well.. I get that I need to store the database into the appdata folder.. And then I need to change the database connection string.. However, I don’t know how to go about moving the database to the appdata folder. Like.. How do I make it so that when the user clicks install, some of the files go to the program files folder, and the database goes to the appdata folder? Maybe I’m not thinking about this correctly..

Comment: how do you actualy install your app? MSI? ClickOnce? Your own installer?

Comment: I was using inno setup and then tried windows installer but.. I’d use whatever you suggest would make this work..

Comment: Inno setup can place files in different folders during setup, check the docs (as I can see it is under `[Files] section` [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/)). Also, your app can create (or copy from embedded resource) database file on the first run (or when database file does not exists)

Comment: Ok I’ll look into it and post a comment if Im still struggling! Thanks so much for your help! I wish I could upvote but I’m too new I guess :(

Comment: You are welcome:) you may mark it as answer (if it answer your question) instead of upvote.